# My button wont stay highlighted when I add a pan gesture recognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`to my `UIButton`. And now my when I drag a short distance with my finger after I pressed the button, the button stops being highlighted. Normally, a UIButton will stay highlighted unless you drag pretty far outside the UIButtons frame. However, with a pan gesture recognizer, now even if I drag a little bit, the button stops being highlighted.

Nothing in my code sets the buttons highlighted property to no. I even tried erasing all the code in my panning gesture recognizers action selector thing(the method that gets called whenever i pan on my button).

I also tried setting the button's highlighted property to NO in the panning gesture recognizer's action selector thing.

This kind of worked its just the highlightedness flashes. When you pan the highlighted goes away then comes back really fast, like a flash. So, this doesnt work too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gestures, by default, will cancel the touches in the views that they are linked to.  So, when the touches in your button get cancelled it becomes unhighlighted.  To prevent this behavior, set the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of your gesture to `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
-(void) panDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gesture 
{
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        yourButton.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_button_highlited_image.png"];
    }
    else if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

    }
    else if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        yourButton.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_button_normal_image.png"];
    }
}
```

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer has no property backgroundImageView

Comment: i still thumbs up though because you efforted :=)

Comment: I copied and pasted my code which has same requirement and is working fine. "self" here is the viewcontroller for which I added the gesturerecognizer. backgroundImageView is a property of it which is actually the background ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. borrrden is right; to fix it, set the viewController the delegate for the gestureRecognizer, and cancel the touch if the touch is on a IUButton. First add the protocol `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate on the .h file. Then, after creating the gesture recognizer, set the view controller as its delegate:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod)];
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
[gestureRecognizer release];
```

Finally override `shouldReceiveTouch`and cancel unwanted touches:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) { //Do not override UIButton touches
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```